# TCPDF giving error when trying to generate a PDF from HTML

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I am trying to generate PDF and save it to a file.

I tested **example_011.php** which is shipped with TCPDF and this also gives error.

Here is the code that I am using.

```
//Capture the document/file that we need to render in PDF
ob_start();

include('perfoma_invoice.php');

$PDFContent = ob_get_contents();

ob_end_clean();

//Start PDF generation Process
require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');

// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Agency');
$pdf->SetTitle('Proforma Invoice');
$pdf->SetSubject('Proforma Invoice');

//We have to check output to decide as we have to set Mono spaced font or not
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

//set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

//set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

//set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO); 

// remove default header/footer
$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

// set JPEG quality
$pdf->setJPEGQuality(75);

// print html formated text
$pdf->writeHtml($PDFContent);

//Build Out File Name with folder where it will be stored
$fName = "VA-PI-" . substr(uniqid(rand(), true), 0, 22) . ".pdf";
$pdf_out_file = "pdf/".$fName;

//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output($pdf_out_file, 'F');
```

The error that I am getting when I test the example: **example_011.php**

```
Warning: fopen(): remote host file access not supported, file://example_011.pdf in D:\laragon\www\vawebnewnew\ws\tcpdf\include\tcpdf_static.php on line 1834

Warning: fopen(file://example_011.pdf): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in D:\laragon\www\vawebnewnew\ws\tcpdf\include\tcpdf_static.php on line 1834
TCPDF ERROR: Unable to create output file: example_011.pdf
```

The function that is giving error in the file **tcpdf_static.php** has following code:

```
/**
     * Wrapper to use fopen only with local files
     * @param string $filename Name of the file to open
     * @param string $mode
     * @return resource|false Returns a file pointer resource on success, or FALSE on error.
     * @public static
     */
    public static function fopenLocal($filename, $mode) {
        if (strpos($filename, '://') === false) {
            $filename = 'file://'.$filename;
        } elseif (stream_is_local($filename) !== true) {
            return false;
        }
        return fopen($filename, $mode);
    }
```

Any ideas as to how to solve this?

One thing I noted is that if I change the code line from:
`$pdf->Output('example_011.pdf', 'F');` to `$pdf->Output('example_011.pdf', 'I');`
The PDF file gets generated and it opens up in the Browser.

TIA

Comment: You are trying to save to the pdf directory thru this line `$pdf_out_file = "pdf/".$fName;`. (1) I suggest you change to use relative path , so will be `$pdf_out_file = "./pdf/".$fName;` (2) make sure that the pdf directory is write-permitted

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I tried that but it still gives error.

Comment: On the second thought it is possible to get TCPDF to generate the PDF and return it as a string by using ```$pdf->Output($pdf_out_file, 'S');```. Can we save this string to PDF file?

Comment: Before `$pdf->Output`, put `ob_clean();`

Comment: I am already calling ```ob_end_clean();``` isn't this enough or should I explicitly call ```ob_clean();```?

Comment: You call it before script, you need `ob_end_clean();ob_start();` before `$pdf->Output()`